# Ubuntu 22.04 Screen Share Pointer Not Visible But Works

Tags: 22.04, vnc, sharing, mouse-pointer

I have two Ubuntu 22.04 desktop systems, on same home wifi. Doing the builtin screen-share (from "Settings") on (let's call it "A").

On "B" (the client), I installed tiger vnc viewer.

If I hover over various window elements in the shared("A's") desktop, they change and I can take the action. But no visible pointer.

The only exception seems to be within a browser, if I hover over any HTML element, such as results links, or "Tools" (to select timeframe: any, past month, etc).

Any ideas? And a question: is this an issue on the server("A"), or on the client("B")?